# VB.NET MySQL Application Will Not Connect on Clients Windows 10 64-bit PC

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, connection

**Hi,

I have built an application in VB.NET to connect to a MySQL database to check users registration, but here is the message that they keep getting each time that they try to run the application and check registration:

"**Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**"

Here is the VB.NET code that I'm using to connect:

```
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=198.27.87.232;userid=MyUserID;password=MyPassword;database=aaronest_ekspdb"
```

'AND I HAVE TRIED:

```
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=198.27.87.232;Port=3306;Database=aaronest_ekspdb;Uid=MyUserID;Pwd=MyPassword;"
```

But still, my client only see's the following message:

**"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."**

The software will connect and run great on most of my clients computers, but for some reason, every now and then, some clients receive the message above.
I have also tried to unblock my clients ports on her Windows 10 firewall to no avail.

Would appreciate the support.**

Comment: BTW, my application checks their registration on my website/domain where the MySQL database and server is located.

Comment: HAve you checked thy mysql logs if there is a problem on that side?

Comment: Hi NBK, where exactly would I check? Would this be in my hosting's cPanel & if so, where exactly? Also, what type message would most likely be present if there are problems?

Comment: he logs should be in standard directory like https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/getting-started-guides/cpanel-logs-for-access-apache-email-error-ftp-mysql-whm First you should log the error times in a file. Then you should ping thw server (sometimes icmp is not allowed) to check it the ip is reachable at all. now you can check in the log file of the Server, if there was a problem at taht time. You can also check windows system events

Comment: Yeah, but I have over 750 clients who are connecting to this database on a regular basis. I don't even have any clue how I would find her IP address in the haystack. Then what would I do if I find some error log? How would I fix the problem? I've had a couple of other people recommend to try a "Connect Timeout" to the string, but I'm not sure if I need to repeat that in a loop multiple times or just 1 time. Just trying to gather ideas at this point.

Comment: Tjs, thst is s problem most programers, who program web apps. as i said earlier, ping bevor you connct.Start a timer that test if server is now available an the connect.

Answer (score 0):

Do the same clients consistently fail, or does a client that once connected successfully experience a failure?

Consider adding Connect Timeout=60 to your connection string to increase the connection timeout from the default of 15 seconds.

Comment: Hi Steve. Yes, the same clients consistently fail (I've only had a few who've had this problem), but most clients have been able to connect without any problems (without this MySQL connection error message). I have had one other person recommend that I try setting the "Connect Timeout" to the string, but not sure that this will fix it. How many times will it retry, just that 1 time after 60 seconds? How would I get it to repeat, just call on the process again in a loop or what would you recommend? Thanks Steve.

Comment: @AaronEsteban it's your responsibility as the code author to handle retries. The connection attempt will be made only once per call. I would typically put the connect in a loop that runs for X attempts then gives up.